Hartshorne vs Vakil
I was trying to find the best resource to start studying scheme theory, and I had a question about the second and third chapter in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry. I'd like to know whether or not their contents (in particular the part about cohomology) is enterely covered in Ravi Vakil's notes, or if Hartshorne is still the best way to learn (by doing all the exercises) schemes and cohomology.
If otherwise Vakil's notes are enough, which are the chapters to study in order to learn cohomology? Thanks in advance to everyone!
